# Android : save/open picture taken from camera intent

Tags: android, permissions, android-camera

I have a camera intent that takes a picture that I want to save anywhere as a temp file :

```
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myTempPicture.jpg");
imageUri =  Uri.fromFile(photo);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

(Maybe the choice of Storage is not the right one)
Then after the picture was taken, I need to open it to process it :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        process(bitmap, false);
    }catch(Exception e){
         Log.d("exception : ", e.toString());
    }
}
```

But I get the following Exception : `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/savedImage.jpg (Permission denied)`.

What went wrong ?

---

My Manifest file contains :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: you did runtime request for storage ?

Comment: No I did not. Should I ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with android 6.0+ or SDK 23 and above you have to ask runtime permission in your activity

here an example how you can do that, here 1 is your request code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
        }
```

and then you should check if user granted permission

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (!(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for more detailed guide about runtime request have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) at official documentation